# Something like `declval` for concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, c++20

When you are working with templates and with `decltype` you often need an instance of a certain type even though you do not have any the moment. In this case, `std::declval<T>()` is incredibly useful. This creates an imaginary instance of the type `T`.

Is there a something similar for concepts? i.e. a function which would create and imaginary type for a concept.

Let me give you an example(a bit contrived but should serve the purpose):

Let's define a concept `Incrementable`

```
template <typename T>
concept Incrementable = requires(T t){
   { ++t } -> T;                       
};
```

Now I would like to have a concept which tests if an object has the operator  `operator()` which can accept `Incrementable`. In my imaginary syntax I would write something like this:

```
template <typename F, typename T = declval<Incrementable>>
concept OperatesOnIncrementable = requires(F f, T t){
   { f(t) } -> T;
}
```

There the `declval` in `typename T = declval<Incrementable>` would create an imaginary type `T` which is not really a concrete type but for all intents and purposes behaves like a type which satisfies `Incrementable`.

Is there a mechanism in the upcoming standard to allow for this? I would find this incredibly useful.

---

Edit: Some time ago I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755702/boosthana-introspection-for-templated-function) if this can be done with `boost::hana`.

---

Edit: Why is this useful? For example if you want to write a function which composes two functions

```
template <typename F, typename G>
auto compose(F f, G g) {
  return [f, g](Incrementable auto x) { return f(g(x)); };
}
```

I want to get an error when I try to compose two functions which cannot be composed. Without constraining the types `F` and `G` I get error only when I try to call the composed function.

Comment: "*I would find this incredibly useful.*" I'm not sure I understand why. Like, I can understand why you would want to constrain a function/class on whether `f(t)` yields a value of type `T`. And I understand why you would want to constrain `T` to being `Incrementable`. But I don't see how it would be useful to constrain a template on the basis of *just `F`*. That is, that someone would use `OperatesOnIncrementable<F>` as a constraint, without providing a `T`. What good is that?

Comment: @NicolBolas I have edited my answer to give an example where it can be useful.

Comment: Why does your `compose` function need to constrain the type passed to the inner function? If you're composing functions, compose them; allow the nature of what `g` takes determine how the composition works.

Comment: @NicolBolas One big advantage of concepts is that they can catch errors early and give you meaningful error messages. In my example, what if you do invalid composition and pass it to some algorithm. You probably get a horrible error from the depths of the algorithm.

Comment: I guess my point is that it's not clear what you mean by "valid" or "invalid" composition in this case. For example, is it "valid" if `g` has multiple overloads of its `operator()`, but only one of them returns a type that `f` takes? If it's not valid... why? If the user never uses those other overloads, why would you want to prevent `g` from having them? The only validity that ultimately counts is what happens when the user fills in the template parameters. *All* of the template parameters.

Comment: @NicolBolas In the composition I would constrain `F` and `G` with `OperatesOnIncrementable`. Therefore, both `f` and `g` can take in any `Incrementable` and spit out an `Incrementable`. I do not see how could `g` produce something which `f` would not accept. Of course, implementing `OperatesOnIncrementable` is probably very difficult.

Comment: You want [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity), but C++ doesn't have it. Templates and concepts don't qualify. If you want a language with parametricity, consider Haskell, OCaml or Scala.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a something similar for concepts? i.e. a function which would create and imaginary type for a concept.

The term for this is an *archetype*. Coming up with archetypes would be a very valuable feature, and is critical for doing things like definition checking. From T.C.'s answer:

> Thus, even if you could magically synthesize some unique type, you still have no guarantee that `F` operates on all `Incrementable` types.

The way to do that would be to synthesize an archetype that as minimally as possible meets the criteria of the concept. As he says, there is no archetype generation in C++20, and is seems impossible given the current incarnation of concepts.

---

Coming up with the correct archetype is incredibly difficult. For example, for

```
template <typename T>
concept Incrementable = requires(T t){
   { ++t } -> T;                       
};
```

It is tempting to write:

```
struct Incrementable_archetype {
    Incrementable_archetype operator++();
};
```

But that is not "as minimal as possible" - this type is default constructible and copyable (not requirements that `Incrementable` imposes), and its `operator++` returns exactly `T`, which is also not the requirement. So a really hardcore archetype would look like:

```
struct X {
    X() = delete;
    X(X const&) = delete;
    X& operator=(X const&) = delete;

    template <typename T> operator,(T&&) = delete;

    struct Y {
        operator X() &&;
    };
    Y operator++();
};
```

If your function works for `X`, then it probably works for all `Incrementable` types. If your function doesn't work for `X`, then you probably need to either change the implementation so it does or change the constraints to to allow more functionality.

For more, check out the [Boost Concept Check Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) which is quite old, but is very interesting to at least read the documentation.

Comment: "Probably" being the keyword. I can give `F` a `void operator()(some-Incrementable-type) = delete;` and your archetype can't detect that.

Answer (score 9):

There is no such mechanism.

Nor does this appear to be implementable/useful, since there is an unbounded number of `Incrementable` types, and `F` could reject a subset selected using an arbitrarily complex metaprogram. Thus, even if you could magically synthesize some unique type, you still have no guarantee that `F` operates on all `Incrementable` types.

Comment: Cannot we just fail the metaprogram if it uses something else then it is guaranteed by the concept?