# Check the existence of a member function template in a concept definition

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Suppose I have a concept `Concept` and a bunch of similar types that provide a member function template as follows:

```
class Typical {
  template<Concept T>
  auto something() { return ...; }
};
```

How do I write a concept `HasSomething` that tests for the existence of such a member template function? Note that the function template has no arguments and is designed to be called as `obj.something<T>()`. I have to test whether the function is callable with any `Concept`.

*Edit*: all the approaches I can think of require to at least provide an instance of `T`. I can imagine how to test whether `Typical::template something` is well-formed if `something` where supposed to be a class template, but not for a function template.

Comment: Did you try to write one? What didn't work?

Comment: I added something to the question. The problem is I don't know how to write a trait that tests whether `Typical::template something` is well-formed without calling it *e.g.* inside `std::void_t<decltype(...)>`, but then I would have to chose a type to call it with.

Comment: There's no way to avoid choosing the argument type.

Comment: You don't test for the existence of a function with a signature. You test for whether an expression is valid. What expression are you going to use in the template that this concept will be applied to? Put that in the `requires` expression, along with whatever template parameters it requires.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks but that would not work in my case. I've edited the question to better align with the real case. I do not have an argument to give to the function to deduce the template parameter. I have to test whether the member function is callable with some type that satisfies `Concept`. But I cannot select one to use for the test, and even if I could, the test would still only test for the expression to be well-formed for that specific type.

Comment: @gigabytes: At some point, you are going to write template code that does this: `value.template something<SomeType>()`, yes? At that point, you have `SomeType`. So put that into the concept, and have your function require that `SomeType` fulfill whatever `Concept` is in addition to your desired concept.

Comment: To add to what @NicolBolas is saying: If you don't have `SomeType` in your codebase because you're making some library, you can create a sample `SomeType` in a test file in some test project.

Comment: You probably want to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598655/2069064) but it's still hard for me to tell what you're asking.